# Adding a function to jqGrid to add local JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jqgrid

I"m trying to create an additional function for jqGrid to simplify adding JSON data to a grid that uses local data.  The following attempt works except for one line, which causes it to fail.

```
  $.fn.myrows = function(data) {
    $(this).clearGridData();
    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json", loadonce: true});
    $("#" + (this).selector)[0].addJSONData(data); // PROBLEMATIC LINE
    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "local", loadonce: true});
  };
```

This function is then called as `$("#myGrid").myrows(jsonDataObject);`.

Note that these lines work when they are not inside this function.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387805/adding-a-function-to-jqgrid-jquery-plugin/6390033#6390033) on your previous question I tried to explain how to extend jqGrid to support new method. To tell the truth, I don't see what real advantage you will have from the jqGrid extending. Why not just define your function as

```
var myrows = function(grid,data) {
    // function body
};
```

and use it in the way:

```
myrows($("#myGrid"),jsonDataObject);
```

Much more important thing in my opinion is the implementation of what you need. Your current code have many disadvantages. If the grid has `datatype: "local"` then the local data paging can be used. The method `addJSONData` add all the data in the grid, so the page size can be broken.

If you have `datatype: "local"` and want to fill it with the data then the most effective way will be to set `data` parameter of the grid with respect of `setGridParam` and then just call `$("#myGrid").trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}])` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014)).

Alternative you can use many other existing methods like [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) which allows to add many rows of data at one method call.

If you get the JSON data from the server and thy to fill the grid with `addJSONData` method it will be really bad way. The versions of jqGrid starting with the version 3.5 has rich ways to customize the `ajax` request used. So it is strictly recommended that you don't use `addJSONData` in the case. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660226/should-one-replace-the-usage-addjsondata-of-jqgrid-to-the-usage-of-setgridparam) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, do this on the line:

`$("#" + $(this).selector)[0].addJSONData(data); // PROBLEMATIC LINE`

The `$` was missing before `this`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem.  Apparently "this" and "$(this)" are the same in this context. Thanks though.

Comment: @Jack: Why not use just `this[0].addJSONData(data);`? The real problem which you has could be not the line. I described how I see the problem in my answer.