# How to export only visible data?

Tags: jqgrid, export

I use this method to export my data:

```
$('#list').jqGrid('getRowData')
```

But now I want the getRowData to return only the data from visible columns.

I hide my columns like so:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('hideCol',columnName)
```

Does jqGrid support this out of the box? Or will I need to build something custom?

Answer (score 2):

The method `getRowData` has no option to export only visible data. So if you need to have the data I can suggest you two implementation ways:

1. You can get all data using `getRowData` and then remove unneeded properties from every item of resulting data. The call `$('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel')` get you array of columns of the grid. Every item of `colModel` array contain `hidden` property. If the `hidden` property is `true` then the corresponding column is non-visible and you can delete `name` property of the item from all items of array returned by `getRowData`.
2. You can define your own modification of `getRowData` which export only visible data. To do this you need make copy of the source code of `getRowData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L3026-L3062)), make modification of [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L3044) from

```js
if ( nm !== 'cb' && nm !== 'subgrid' && nm !== 'rn') {
```

to

```js
if ( nm !== 'cb' && nm !== 'subgrid' && nm !== 'rn' && !$t.p.colModel[i].hidden) {
```

The resulting method will do what you need.

I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390033/315935) how you can add new method to jqGrid. So your code can be something like

```
$.jgrid.extend({
    getVisibleRowData: function(rowid) {
        // here can be the copy of the code of getRowData 
        // starting with the line
        //    var res = {}, resall, getall=false, len, j=0;
        // see https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L3027-L3061
        // you need just make the described above
        // modification of one line of the code
    }
});
```

You can use new method by name: `$('#list').jqGrid('getVisibleRowData')`.